# Repeat loop until input valid for fraction class

Tags: java

I am doing a simple fraction test class. I want my program to do this.

IF a user input 0  >  the loop repeats until the user enter a number that not 0

In my class, it not doing that. I tried to mixed it with `do while` conditions with `if` statements plus initializing if the statement `true` or `false`. Im stuck so please I need help.

Here my fraction Class:

```
import java.util.*;


public class FractionTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean valid = true;
        int num, den;

        den = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the numerator: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the denominator: ");
            den = input.nextInt();
            if (den == 0 && valid) {
                System.out.println("denominator cannot be zero");
                System.out.println("Please enter the numerator: ");
                num = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please enter the denominator: ");
                den = input.nextInt();
            }

        } while (den != 0 && !valid);
        System.out.println("Decimal is " + result(num, den));
    }

    public static double result(int x, int y) {
        return (x / y);

    }
}
```

[Here the program once I run the Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nor1e.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on "it not doing that": what is it doing instead?  Specify the inputs and the expected behavior/output.

Comment: Are you sure `result` returns what you think it does?

Comment: It doesn't look like you change the value of valid anywhere in your loop

Comment: Also, if you want the loop to repeat when the user inputs 0, then it looks like you should have den == 0 instead of den != 0 in your while condition

Comment: @ScottHunter  I edit the post forgive me. I want my program to run the loop until the user enter a number that not 0

Comment: Another note, there should be no need to repeat the questions in the if(den == 0 && valid) statement, since once you fix everything up the loop should repeat meaning it will ask the questions again

Comment: @bradimus If you test my program it will run the loop the second time if you type 0 as the denominator but if you keep enter 0 as the denominator it will break the loop and the complier will try to calculate the fraction as 0 as the denominator

Comment: @KashadT: That's not what compilers do.

Comment: @KashadT That is because you ask the questions twice in one iteration of the loop, check out Rusheel's answer below, it looks good

Comment: @KashadT the main problem is that you run `while den != 0` which means that it gets out of while loop when den becomes 0. This is the reason you are getting Arithemetic exception

Comment: My question was not about the loop. What do you expect `result(2,3)` to return? (Currently, it will return `0.0`)

Comment: As it is `int / int` we have to multiply `1.0` to typecast the `int`. Nice point @bradimus

Comment: @NikhilPathania I research other post and others say that using a do while loop so I tried to initalized if `den == 0 && valid` are met and vice verse. maybe i did not fully understand the boolean operators in my code correctly

Comment: @bradimus I expect to return a decimal value. once I get my program to output decimal value without denimator being zero. I want to see if i can it to return fraction form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the code in the main-method to this:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num, den;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter the numerator: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the denominator: ");
        den = input.nextInt();
        if (den!=0)
            System.out.println("Decimal is " + result(num, den));
        else
            System.out.println("Denominator shouldnt be 0");
    } while (den == 0);
    input.close();
```

1. There was no need to initialized 'den' as the value is anyways replaced.
2. There was no need of having 'boolean variable' as its value never change
3. if den==0, no need to re-ask for inputs within the loop as the loop should 
   anyways re-run

Comment: It worked, all the other postal I saw recommend to do the boolean true statement if I want the loop keep repeating itself until the denominator is not 0. I just curious what went wrong in my program?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not completely clear but I think that you are asking that whenever denominator becomes zero continue loop else calculate answer and return value. I made some changes to your code according to that

```
public class FractionTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean valid = true;
    int num, den;

    den = 0;

    while(den == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the numerator: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the denominator: ");
        den = input.nextInt();
        if (den == 0 && valid) {
            System.out.println("denominator cannot be zero");
            System.out.println("Please enter the numerator: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the denominator: ");
            den = input.nextInt();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Decimal is " + result(num, den));
    return;
}

public static double result(int x, int y) {
    return ((1.0)*x / y);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would just separate your input validations:

```
        System.out.println("Please enter the numerator: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter the denominator: ");
        System.out.println("denominator cannot be zero");
        den = input.nextInt();
    } while (den == 0);
    System.out.println("Decimal is " + result(num, den));
```

If you need an input validation for your numerator just do a do while around that. Also your boolean value for valid is always true. Never modified to be false. Logic (x ^ True) will always be if x is true.